# force encoding within javascript_include_tag

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, encoding, cross-domain, haml

I have the webpage with UTF-8 encoding and some remote JS file which writes some text to the document. The text JS writes seems to be WIN-1251 encoded. So, the question is: how can i force that JS writing all the text in UTF-8?

**Note:** using rails 3 and haml. JS writes content with `document.write`.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but: don't use `document.write`.

Comment: that's why that script is remote ;) actually, i even do not know who originally wrote that =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using MVC: now just rendering loaded model data. When loading that data it is converted with Iconv passing encodings detected manually as arguments for `Iconv.iconv`.